# Creating a JSON in RMarkdown and then reading/parsing it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, r, json, r-markdown, same-origin-policy

I have an RMarkdown like this:

````
```r
library(jsonlite)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)


arrest_data <- tbl(criminal_history_db, sql("select * from 
arrests_table)
"
))

arrest_data <- as.data.frame(arrest_data) 

arrest_data_JSON <- toJSON(arrest_data,dataframe="columns")

write(arrest_data_JSON, "//my_files/arrest_data.JSON")

```


```{js}
  //this fails
  $.getJSON("//my_files/arrest_data.JSON", function(json) {
      console.log(json); // this will show the info in console
  });
```
````

All of this works and I'm able to produce a JSON. But when I try to read in the local JSON using JavaScript, it of course fails due to a CORS error:

Is there a way to have JavaScript read in the JSON I've created using R syntax? In other words, eliminate the step where I'm saving the JSON locally? I don't have a server framework, I'd like everything to be self-contained in RMarkdown.

Maybe this would work if the JSON was hosted online somewhere, like Box or Sharepoint?

Comment: Yep, you'll have to use some sort of webserver or host it somewhere else.

Comment: Do you mean something as simple as hosting the JSON online, like with Box, Google Drive, etc?  Would that do the trick?  thanks!

Comment: Maybe see here for hosting: https://geekflare.com/best-json-hosting/

Comment: You can also host on Github.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this helps, but if you run a server in the current directory before knitting then it works. That is:

```
servr::httd()
# knit your file
servr::daemon_stop(1)
```

Tested with:

````
```{r}
library(jsonlite)
write(toJSON(list(1, 2, 3)), "test.json")
```

```{js}
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
  console.log(json); // this will show the info in console
});
```
````

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify, where exactly am I putting "servr:httd()" etc?  Is this in the RMarkdown or somewhere else?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 you run it in the console before knitting your file

Comment: Hi! This works, thanks, but for some reason it seems to freeze R after I knit the RMarkdown to HTML.  It basically just turns into a blank R screen and freezes.  Not sure what's up with that.